# Google Analytics Structure

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to build a custom Analytics App. I am just wondering a few things.

Google Analytics contains Accounts which in turn contains Web Properties which in return gives you the Profile Id.

Just wanted to know can Accounts have mutiple Web Properties and Web properties have multiple Profile ids ?

how are these naming conventions work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got that right.

Google Analytics accounts can have multiple webproperties that in turn can have multiple profiles.

When you send data to GA you send it to a Web Property. A Web Property Id has the form UA-123456-1. So a Web Property is where your data is collected.

Profiles are visualizations of your data. If you create a lot of profiles they will look exactly the same, except if you implement filters to change or filter the data that goes into that profile.

Goals, Adv Segments,  Annotations, scheduled emails and alerts are all properties of the profile.

An Administrator has Access to all WPs and Profiles in the account it has access to. So Accounts are a good way to organize Access.

Users with normal "User" access, must be granted access on each individual profile.